# How safe is it to drive with no muffler?

Tags: nissan, fuel-tank, muffler

I drive a 2007 Nissan Versa with 248,000 km on it. The other day, as I was driving, The section where my muffler pipe should be welder or otherwise attached to the flange broken off. Basically my muffler was completely detached from the vehicle, and was hanging from its mounts. I removed it last night so it’s partly straight piped. I am waiting to bring it to work after my semester finished and hiring a welder to weld it back on to the flange.

In the meantime tho, I am wondering if this is a potential fire hazard, considering the close proximity of the fuel tank? Basically the exhaust is just dumping out under the car and not out the back, so I just figured I’d ask.

Comment: Also, note that because the muffler is missing, your car is probably a lot louder than normal, which could be very annoying to the people around you. And depending on your jurisdiction, it could very well be illegal.

Comment: Thanks marcelm I was kinda concerned about it. However it’s not very loud surprisingly

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is near the hole; that is, what the exhaust blowing toward. Gas tank and lines, brake lines and electric wire would be especially vulnerable to damage. A header pipe ( manifold to first converter/muffler, etc.) is hotter than an intermediate pipe. While on vacation I got a hole in a header pipe ; I made a crude temporary patch to drive for two days to get home ( because it was blowing at the floor of the car and started the rug to burn.). I would not consider it if any heat can drift toward the gas tank. And I would only consider it for a couple days while selecting a repair source. Many places will give fines for the noise.

Comment: I repaired a brken exhaust pipe with a coke can and two hose clamps.. got me home...

Comment: My problem , nearly all cans are aluminum and it melted. I had to wrap with mineral wool and then put on the aluminum  soda cans . Steel cans would have been great.